# How do I get the route name of a view page?

Tags: views, 8, routes

In my custom submit handler I want to redirect to a view page Url, let's suppose my view name is *team* and its path is `/admin/team`, I find out I should  use `$from_state->setRedirect('route');` but when I tried `$from_state->setRedirect('/admin/team');` Faced with error, How can I get view route name in?

Comment: This is also required for static YAML menu configuration.

Comment: Not direct response, but I had same question to links to a custom view in another custom module so in configration file menu :  MODULE.links.menu.yml create a node with route option   `route_name: view.YOUR_CUSTOM_MODULE_CONTAINS_CUSTOM_CONTENT_TYPE.page_1` if page_1 is a name of page view mode.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The correct routename for view is `view.VIEW_MACHINE_NAME.PAGE_MACHINENAME`(in another word `"view.$view_id.$display_id"` ) . try something like following

```
use \Drupal\Core\Url;

$url = Url::fromRoute('view.VIEW_MACHINE_NAME.PAGE_MACHINENAME');
$form_state->setRedirectUrl($url);
```

and for your case

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('view.team.page_1'); // page_1 is my guess as to your page name, please replace it with your page machine_name
```

Lean more : [How to formulate the route name](https://www.computerminds.co.uk/drupal-code/drupal-8-views-how-formulate-route-name)

after @4k4 comment, Also you can redirect form to custom router with URL

just need use `$form_state->setRedirectUrl($url)`

Comment: This answer is a little off, as you are getting the correct routename for the view, so there is no need to create a URL object from that routename. You should be able to use the routename directly:

`$form_state->setRedirect('view.VIEW_MACHINE_NAME.PAGE_MACHINENAME');`

Answer (score 11):

To use views contextual filters as parameters use arg_X, fe.

```
$url = Url::fromRoute('view.team.page_1', ['arg_0' => 1234]);
```

Comment: Admitting your view page path is `foo/%user/bar`, then `$url = Url::fromRoute('view.team.page_1', ['user' => 1234]);`

Answer (score 4):

The Webprofiler of the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module let's you see the route of any page.

It also displays the number of DB queries made on the page and also the request time in addition to many other features.

It's available for Drupal 7 and 8.

Answer (score 3):

Simple example: It will work :)

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
$form_state->setRedirect('view.VIEW_MACHINE_NAME.PAGE_MACHINENAME'); // view.my_view.page_1
```

Comment: No need to use Drupal\Core\Url - you are using the route correctly so the URL class is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

With drush you can check by path for example:

```
drush route | grep '/path/you/are/looking/for'
```

Comment: A time saver not only for views. Thx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 8 you might look into the "router" database table aswell to get your redirect parameters.

Look for the corresponding value in the "name" column and compare against the path column.

```
$form_state->setRedirect('YOUR_DB_VALUE_HERE');
```

Answer (score 1):

With drupal console:

```
drupal router:debug | grep '/admin/team'
```

This returns:

```
 view.team.page_1    /admin/team   // views.team.page_1 is my route
```

Source: https://stefvanlooveren.me/blog/get-route-views-page-drupal-console

Answer (score 0):

An easy trick to show the route name of every page (not just views pages) you can use [`hook_menu_local_tasks_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/8.2.x):

```
function HOOK_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name)
{
  dump($route_name);
}
```