# How do I hide the tab menu link when a view is empty?

Tags: views, 9

I have a view with a menu tab link and an attachment, which displays rows of other nodes, depending on the contextual filter.

This view has a custom path(*/node/%node/view-custom-path*).

How do I show the menu link only when the following conditions are met?

- The node has some taxonomy terms
- The view attachment is empty

I have already set the needed term as filter criteria, but the link ignores it and it's shown everywhere.
I can display an empty message and send 404 headers when the view is empty, but how can I hide the link as well?

I tried using basic validation in contextual filters and setting *Hide view* or *Show page not found*, but that didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried implementing a custom access callback for the route? That's where I'd usually attempt to solve this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, [get the route name of the view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/223407/66659). Then, [alter that route](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones#s-altering-existing-routes), giving it a [custom access callback](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes/custom-route-access-checking) that checks required conditions. Deny access if they are not met. Tabs are only shown if/when the user has access to the route.